# Images Have Strange Tint Only in Firefox

Tags: css, image, firefox

I am having an issue with Firefox rendering a few of the .png's that I have loaded into a Wordpress blog that I am preparing for a client. The images look fine in IE 8 & 9, and chrome, but it looks very off in Mozilla. I was informed by our other UX guy that Firefox complies with embedded color profiles that may warp the tint of your image. You can view the tint shift by going to :

http://blog.hendrickspower.com

If anybody has any idea of how to over ride the color profile, I'd definitely appreciate the heads up!

Thanks

Here is an image that shows the difference that I am seeing.

[alt http://s11.postimage.org/jbnzek4g3/color_embed.jpg](http://s11.postimage.org/jbnzek4g3/color_embed.jpg)

Comment: your page looks the same in FF and Chrome on my computer...

Comment: You can try to remove all unnecessary info from the png's by using [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/).

Comment: As a sidenote: `.entry-utility{disply:none;}` looks wrong (typo)

Comment: I also see no difference. Can you post a screen cap of the two, side by side?

Comment: Like the the "side by side" part.

Comment: @j08691: "There are only 10 types of people in the world: Those who understand binary, and those who don't." - Are you referring to the Principle of Bivalance & The Law of Exluded Middle?

Comment: You should post this in http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @j08691: I guess I am the "mue" type.

Comment: i see the difference in the images you posted, but those differences do not show up when I look at them side by side on my computer

Comment: Have you tried messing with this: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Gfx.color_management.mode ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference in rendering is due to an ICC color profile embedded in the image. When Firefox finds a color profile it will combine it with the color profile of the display and adjust image rendering accordingly. This will normally make sure that the image is displayed the same on different displays. However, it might also cause undesired effects if the display profile is incorrect.

At least Windows 7 allows you to [calibrate display colors](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/calibrate-your-display). Not sure whether this feature was also present in earlier Windows versions but they definitely allowed selecting a color profile file in the advanced display settings - you could replace the driver-supplied profile by sRGB.

If you absolutely don't want different image display on different computers then you should just remove the color profile from the image with a tool like [jStrip](http://davidcrowell.com/jstrip/) and [pngcrush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush#Reducing_filesize_by_removing_color-correction_data).